# Select top n records based on ordinal and attribute data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a case where I need to show only the top rows based on a setting in a table and the ordinal set.

Example dataset below shows two customers; each of the customers have a different product. 
Since `NumRowsToShow` is "1" I only want to show one row (the top row based on ordinal) for EACH Customer.

```
| CustomerID | ProductID | Ordinal | NumRowsToShow |
+------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
| 1          |A          |1        |1              |
| 1          |B          |2        |1              |
| 1          |C          |3        |1              |
| 5          |D          |1        |1              |
| 5          |E          |2        |1              |
| 5          |F          |3        |1              |
```

The result set after query is run should be

```
| CustomerID | ProductID |
+------------+-----------+
| 1          |A          |
| 5          |D          |
```

In the same scenario if `NumRowsToShow` were 1 for customerID 1 and 2 for CustomerID 5 I would see something like.

```
| CustomerID | ProductID | Ordinal | NumRowsToShow |
+------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
| 1          |A          |1        |1              |
| 1          |B          |2        |1              |
| 1          |C          |3        |1              |
| 5          |D          |1        |2              |
| 5          |E          |2        |2              |
| 5          |F          |3        |2              |
```

The result set after query is run should be

```
| CustomerID | ProductID |
+------------+-----------+
| 1          |A          |
| 5          |D          |
| 5          |E          |
```

How can this be done?

Including a screen cap of actual result set with highlights of what I'm trying to filter down to which may be a little helpful.

[image: Screencap]
<sub>(source: [harpernet.net](http://www.harpernet.net/se/cap01.jpg))</sub>

Comment: And what if a customer's rows had three different `NumRowsToShow` (say 1,2,3)?

Comment: That would not happen; NumRowsToShow comes from a setting per CustomerID. It's the same. This is a result from several queries. Customer / ProductID are not the actual result sets, I'm just trying to provide a simple example of what I'm trying to filter down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It feels like "cheating in the exams":

```
SELECT CustomerID, ProductID
FROM tableX
WHERE Ordinal <= NumRowsToShow
```

---

If, as comments suggest, the `Ordinal` can have `10, 20, 30` values and not only `1, ..., n` values, then this will work:

```
SELECT t.CustomerID, t.ProductID
FROM tableX AS t
  JOIN tableX AS tt
    ON  tt.CustomerID = t.CustomerID
    AND tt.Ordinal <= t.Ordinal
GROUP BY t.CustomerID
       , t.ProductID
       , t.NumRowsToShow
HAVING COUNT(*) <= t.NumRowsToShow
```

or even better, the:

```
SELECT CustomerID, ProductID
FROM
  ( SELECT CustomerID, ProductID, NumRowsToShow
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY CustomerID 
                              ORDER BY Ordinal
                            ) AS Rn
    FROM tableX
  ) AS tmp
WHERE Rn <= NumRowsToShow ;
```

Test in: [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f26e0/3)

---

Your table looks to be not normalized. The `NumRowsToShow` columns has duplicate infomation and that can lead to update anomalies. This:

```
| CustomerID | ProductID | Ordinal | NumRowsToShow |
+------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
| 1          |A          |1        |1              |
| 1          |B          |2        |1              |
| 1          |C          |3        |1              |
| 5          |D          |1        |2              |
| 5          |E          |2        |2              |
| 5          |F          |3        |2              |
```

could be normalized to 2 tables:

```
| CustomerID | ProductID | Ordinal |
+------------+-----------+---------+
| 1          |A          |1        |
| 1          |B          |2        |
| 1          |C          |3        |
| 5          |D          |1        |
| 5          |E          |2        |
| 5          |F          |3        |
```

and:

```
| CustomerID | NumRowsToShow |
+------------+---------------+
| 1          |1              |
| 5          |2              |
```

Comment: The table is the result of another query; this is just used as a simple example of the resulting data set that I'm trying to filter down. I like the simple approach of Ordinal <= NumRowsToShow. It almost works, with the exception that "Ordinal" may be 10, 20, 30 .. does not have to be 1, 2,3.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to response. The Partition statement is exactly what I was looking for. I was going down this road but could not find the right way to structure it. Very, very much appreciated for the help.